# Unity - How to Reset Notification Badge on iOS using Firebase Messaging

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending a message from our server we set the flag to increase the badge by 1. When we tap the notification, the OnMessage is called but the badge count doesn't decrement.

The documentation is very minimal, probably because there isn't very much functionality. I read in another post that the FirebaseMessaging.options can be set telling it to decrement after opening the notification but I can't find those options. Also, it seems there is no way to check for permissions either, but that's another issue.

I'm using Unity 2022.3.4f1 with Firebase SDK 11.2.0